# RStudio - ability to string-replace over files in multiple directories?

Tags: r, replace, rstudio-server

Working on R scripts on our RStudio Pro server.

Is there any editing capability to string-replace over files in multiple directories, multiple projects?

Ctrl-Shift-j allows me to *find* the string in R scripts over multiple directories, but not to *replace* them (unless there's a magic switch some where that I'm overlooking.)

Background: I gave a function an unfortunate name in my personal utilities package.  I used that function in at least 8 different projects.  Now I want to give it a better name and update all my projects.

`emacs` has `M-x Tags Query Replace` but I can't load `emacs` on RStudio Pro.  I'm about ready to use `git` to move all my files to directories where I *do* have `emacs`, but that's a lot of rigmarole.

(I'm aware that I could write an R script to do this, but I want to know if RStudio has any native capability.)